# New EE Router not working with netgear swtich?

Tags: windows, router, switch

I had a setup where my PC (and other items) was connected via a netgear switch which was connected to my sky router. This all worked nicely.

Then I changed to EE just now. It no longer works (cant get to the internet or even ping the EE router).

If I connect my PC directly to the EE router I can get to the internet. After a conversation with EE they just say they don't support netgear stuff.... I don't really understand how it can't work through a switch?
Surely saying that they don't support a switch is like saying saying they don't support ethernet cable?!

I am thinking it must be something to do with their router, right?
I also noticed that the EE router either reboots or resets when I was switch between my switch and direct PC connection (i.e. all the lights go out and then slowly come back on)... something very strange is happening there...

Anyway, any idea how I can fix this - or what to try?

I have a windows PC (win 8).

Answer (score 0):

Does the link light come on? If not you might need a crossover cable or a standard 4-pair cable. 2-pair cables just support 100 Mbit/s and don't link at 1 Gbit/s *at all* unless at least one side supports fallback to 100M. Even today, some ports don't support Auto MDI-X and still require a crossover between a switch and a (router-integrated) switch.